# How to reinstall ubuntu on windows 8

Tags: system-installation

I have an ASUS K56CM which I installed Ubuntu 12.04 on, but it kept freezing so I upgraded to 14.04 but somewhere during the install the driver for my Nvidia graphics card was corrupted and now when I boot to Ubuntu I get a black screen with a flashing cursor.

I have tried to boot from a USB to do a fresh install of 13.10 but I cant seem to get it to work.

I have formatted the usb with UUI and hold F12 on boot like before but it doesn't work. 
What am I doing wrong?

Also when I start up my device I still have the option to boot windows 8 which runs fine.

I have tried refreshing and reinstalling windows 8 so I can start over but it says I am missing an important partition or do not have the permissions to do this.

What is the best way to get my device running on Ubuntu again?

Thank you for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

Currently reinstalling Ubuntu on Windows 8 is not supported.

There are a lot of things that could be wrong with why it is not working.

- Have you enabled "Legacy" booting in the bios?

[image: Enable Legacy booting]

- Are you able to boot from that particular USB from another computer?
- Maybe try using the  [YUMI
  installer](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/)
  if in windows?
- Trying to  [dual
  boot](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot) will be more difficult than doing a full install.
- If you have installed Ubuntu alongside Windows check the partitions on the hard drive with [(diskpart)](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/300415/en-us) or [(fdisk)](http://manpages.courier-mta.org/htmlman8/fdisk.8.html)

Generally a blinking cursor means that the motherboard is not loading the OS, but there are also a lot of reason why there could a blinking cursor, and the amount of [(troubleshooting for a blinking cursor)](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1743535&highlight=black) can get rather in depth.

The most straight forward solution would be to  [(burn the iso to a DVD)](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BurningIsoHowto) and  [(boot from the cd drive.)](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootFromCD).

If dual booting:

You may need to [shrink your windows partition,](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowtoResizeWindowsPartitions) before installing Ubuntu.